# Start ripple in a Floating Action Button programatically

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have a floating action button in my app, it has the ripple color attribute set via XML. I want to make the button to ripple continuously to get the user attention.

How can I make the floating action button to ripple programatically? I tried using `callOnClick()` but it just calls the `onClick()` method without any ripples.

Comment: You could take a look into [this library](https://github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background) and tweak around with the options to achieve the required feature.

Answer (score 2):

Add following 2 properties in xml file

```
app:rippleColor="@color/yourcolor"
 android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: This will give my button a ripple when I click it. I have done that already. I want a buy by which the button will always be in ripple mode.